# Accessing MySQL5.7 Docker container results in zsh: command not found: mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, zsh

I am simply trying to run MySQL container using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and access it in my localhost.

This may be simple and easy to solve, but i am really struggling to find solution.

I have been googling around with the following searches, but i have no luck.

```
"zsh:command not found: mysql using Docker"

"docker, z shell problem"

"docker, zsh:command not found"

"etc..."
```

I am assuming this has something to do with [z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), but I have no clue how to fix this.

## Here are the steps I did in my [iTerm2 terminal](https://www.iterm2.com/).

#### Run MySQL 5.7 docker container

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 \
  -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true \
  --name mysql \
  mysql:5.7
```

#### Access MySQL to test, but failed

```
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot
```

> > zsh: command not found: mysql

Answer (score 0):

You should install mysql-client to use mysql to connect on your container.

Answer (score 0):

Because your MySQL is installed in a docker container and not in local via `brew`, you can access your MySQL interface by running

`docker exec -it nameofyourMySQLContainer mysql -u root -p`

Enter your password if you've set one up for the container and then you're in